# weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException

Tags: java, weblogic12c

**i am trying to deploy an a application on weblogic but i am getting that error. Can anyone tell me what is the solution?**

Error An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.

> Error weblogic.jdbc.extensions.ConnectionDeadSQLException:
> weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException:
> 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection
> for datasource 'TOSKA-Tea-BOA-QDB-DS'. **The DBMS driver exception was:
> IO Error: An established connection was aborted by the software in
> your host machine**, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
>
> Error weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceDeadException:
> 0:weblogic.common.ResourceException: Could not create pool connection
> for datasource 'TOSKA-Tea-BOA-QDB-DS'. **The DBMS driver exception was:
> IO Error: An established connection was aborted by the software in
> your host machine**, Authentication lapse 0 ms.

Comment: Your application needs a jdbc datasource (TOSKA-Tea-BOA-QDB-DS) which is not well configured to access the database. Have a look to your domain configuration and check this datasource.

Comment: There was a missing jdbc file i added it and now it is working well.